# How to get list of supported argument in V (command line)

Tags: vlang

I have installed v using the official [doc](https://github.com/vlang/v/blob/master/doc/docs.md#linux-macos-freebsd-etc) on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The installation was successful as I can check the version:

```
$ v version
V 0.2.4 310969a
```

When I tried to see the supported args using help arg, it is resulting in an error.

```
$ v help
`v help`: unknown help topic provided. Use `v help` for usage information.
Known help topics:
```

I tried `v help, v --help, v -help, v --h, v -h` but all resulted in an error.

Thanks.

Comment: try restarting your terminal?

Comment: could also be that you should put the command/topic u want help with like 'v help topic'

Comment: @GamingFelix Restarted. Same problem: `v help
`v help`: unknown help topic provided. Use `v help` for usage information.
Known help topics:`

Comment: what do you get if you do: v help help ?

Comment: @GamingFelix `$ v help help
`v help`: unknown help topic provided. Use `v help` for usage information.
Known help topics:`

Comment: Found this in the documentation: 
To see a detailed list of all flags that V supports, use v help, v help build and v help build-c.

So if you find a command you wanna get info about you do :
v help command

I guess the part you're not printing out or not getting is that list of commands. 
But yeah, try v help build. Or check the documentation you linked. Everything is there.

Comment: @GamingFelix Tried `$ v help build` got the same error. `$ v help build
`v help`: unknown help topic provided. Use `v help` for usage information.
Known help topics:`

Comment: I got no idea then, I'd suggest you just keep checking the documentation. There's some hello world program you can try there. I also saw it mentions, symlink. I assume you checked that too

( It is recommended to add this folder to the PATH of your environment variables. This can be done with the command v.exe symlink )

Comment: @GamingFelix Ok. Thanks for replying. Weill look into more docs

Comment: @GamingFelix Creating the symlink did work. Thanks

Comment: No problems! Glad it worked out

Answer (score 1):

The more safe way to install `v` compiler it uses the following command

```sh
git clone https://github.com/vlang/v.git
cd v
make
make install
```

This will use the C compiler to build v and also `symlink` it without that you know nothing.

```
sudo ./v symlink
```

After that you can use both `v --help` and `v help`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you just keep checking the documentation. There's some hello world program you can try there. I also saw it mentions, symlink.

( It is recommended to add this folder to the PATH of your environment variables. This can be done with the command v.exe symlink )